# Displaying multiple integers after atoi

Tags: c++

I've been trying to make a table that displays all grades with a function that will display if the grade is passed or failed. When I used atoi it converts the past records to either symbols or blanks. What can I do to make sure that the previous records would not be affected and will stay as strings like they should be? Here is a portion of code that I made. I want to display it to the textfile which serves as a record book for all of the grades the user is going to enter. The if statements at the very bottom work.

```
        int TotalRecords = 0;
        string ArrName[50], ArrGrade[50];
        for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++)
        {
            if (ArrName[x] == "\0")
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                TotalRecords++;
                cout << left
                     << TotalRecords << ".   " 
                     << setw(30) << ArrName[x] 
                     << setw(3) << ArrGrade[x]
                     << "    ";

            int gradeCalc = atoi(ArrGrade[x].c_str());
                ArrGrade[x] = gradeCalc;
                if (gradeCalc < 75)
                {
                    cout << "Failed" << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Passed" << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        if (TotalRecords == 0)
        {
            cout << "No records found!" << endl;
        }
```

Comment: Why are you doing `int gradeCalc = atoi(ArrGrade[x].c_str());` folowed by `ArrGrade[x] = gradeCalc;`.  If `ArrDrade` is an array of strings, then the second line should faile to compile.  Please [edit] your question to contain a [mre]

Comment: I wasn't sure if the value of ArrGrade will be maintained after using atoi so I tried that first.